# Send Mongodb logs to AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: mongodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a mongodb log file in an EC2 instance and I would like to send the logs to AWS cloud watch.

The file is at the default location of a linux AMI : /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

What do I have to do send these logs to cloudwatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install awslog agent on ec2 instance.

```
sudo yum install awslogs
```

Edit file /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf and verify following lines

```
[/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = AMZ-2
```

Start and enable awslogsd service by typing the command:

```
$ sudo service awslogsd start
$ sudo systemctl  enable awslogsd
```